# Turn columns' values to headers of columns with values 1 and 0 ( accordingly) [python]

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, matrix

I got a column of the form :

```
0           q4
1           4
2           3   
3           1
4           2
5           1
6           5
7           1
8           3
```

The column represents the answers of users to a question of 5 choices (1-5).

I want to turn this into a matrix of 5 columns where the indexes are the 5 possible answers and the values are 1 or 0 according to the user's given answer.

Visualy i want a matrix of the form:

```
0   q4_1  q4_2  q4_3  q4_4 q4_5
1   Nan    Nan   Nan   1    Nan
2   Nan    Nan   1    Nan   Nan
3   1      Nan   Nan  Nan   Nan
4   Nan    1     Nan  Nan   Nan
5   1      Nan   Nan  Nan   Nan
```

Comment: `pd.get_dummies(df['q4'])`

Comment: Thank  you for your comment. If possible, could you tell me  how i could get the columns of just certain of the 5 answers, and not all of them? @QuangHoang

Comment: `pd.get_dummies(df['q4']).reindex([1,2,3,4,5], axis=1)`.

Comment: That actually returns a matrix of 4 colums (in the case that i dont want to consider the 5th answer) of just Nan. @QuangHoang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(1,6):
    df['q4_'+str(i)]=np.where(df.q4==i, 1, 0)

def df['q4']
```

Output:

```
>>> print(df)

   q4_1  q4_2  q4_3  q4_4  q4_5
0     0     0     0     1     0
1     0     0     1     0     0
2     1     0     0     0     0
3     0     1     0     0     0
4     1     0     0     0     0
5     0     0     0     0     1
6     1     0     0     0     0
7     0     0     1     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think pivot is the way to go. You'd have to prepopulate the df with the info you want in the new table.
Also, I don't understand why you want only 5 rows but I added it as well in `iloc`. If you remove it, you will have this data for your entire index (up to 8).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'q4': [4, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 3]})
df.index += 1
df['values'] = 1
df = df.reset_index().pivot(index='q4', columns='index', values='values').T.iloc[:5]
```

prints

```
q4     1    2    3    4   5
index                        
1    NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0 NaN
2    NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN NaN
3    1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
4    NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN
5    1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
```